# Run Windows Server 2012 Datacenter headless

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2, headless

Is there a way to run a full installation of Windows Server 2012 headless? I am aware that I could potentially uninstall the GUI but I'm looking for a more 'seamless' solution where I could easily switch between GUI and CMD between reboots.

What I'm looking for is something similar to Ubuntu server where you can switch into the GUI by doing a 'startx' and vice-versa.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: what exactl;y are you trying to do - install or manage without the gui?

Comment: I have a full install, i.e. with GUI. I'd like to boot headless to keep it running without the gui overhead but occasionally boot into gui fir maintenance tasks etc.

Comment: Again, why on earth has this question been downvoted?

Comment: in that case the accepted answer is incorrect you can certainly add the gui on at any time.  There is no requirement for windows to have a monitor or keyboard attached.

Comment: @JimB How would I go about doing that? The xml file you mention, is it a configuration file?

Comment: The unattend file is for the install (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff699026.aspx) see this thread for how to manage the GUI https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/6eb62cdc-ae43-48b1-873e-9903c3bc73a7/powershell-to-add-gui-to-server-core-servercorefullserver?forum=winserver8gen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Windows just doesn't work that way.

Comment: Is server core still a thing? That's perhaps about as close as one could get.

Comment: headlessunattend.xml still exists in 2012, and that can be configured to install the gui (or not) as desired.  The WAIK has documentation on how t do headless installs.